# How to give back button to toolbar in ListActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listactivity

I need to give back button to toolbar which extends ListActivity

I have been using following codes to add back button to toolbar

```
// Adding Toolbar to Main screen
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
    // Adding Toolbar to Main screen
    toolbar.setTitle("Please Confirm Your Action");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But all those activity extends AppCompatActivity.But now I need to give back button in ListActivity and it returns error in  setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Please help

Comment: `ListActivity` isn't a support `Activity`. You need to use `getActionBar()` / `setActionBar()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I done is i have included a back button using an image like this

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
```

Then I add an setNavigationOnClickListener on the toolbar and finished the activity

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```